# KDB/Q how to match and join a fifo calculation in a table

Tags: q

I have a trade table

```
trades:flip `ts`buyer`seller`price`qty!(`t1`t2`t3`t4`t5;`a`b`a`x`x;`x`x`x`z`z;10 10 9 10 11;200 500 100 300 500)

ts  buyer   seller  price   qty
t1  a   x   10  200
t2  b   x   10  500
t3  a   x   9   100
t4  x   z   10  300
t5  x   z   11  500
```

I would like to somehow match the z trades to the a and b trades

```
flip `ts`buyer`seller`price`qty`price_z!(`t1`t2`t3`t4`t5;`a`b`a`x`x;`x`x`x`z`z;10 10 9 10 11;200 500 100 300 500;10 10.8 11 0 0)

ts  buyer   seller  price   qty price_z
t1  a   x   10  200 10.0  <-- allocating 200 shares from the first trade of 300 @ 10
t2  b   x   10  500 10.8  <-- allocating the remaining 100 shares of the first trade @ 10 and 400 from the second trade @ 11
t3  a   x   9   100 11.0  <-- allocating the remaining 100 shares @ 11
t4  x   z   10  300 0.0
t5  x   z   11  500 0.0
```

I cant see any way to do this other than iterating over rows, keeping information of trades and updating the table, but doing this in qpython would be painfully slow for large tables, so I was wondering if the immortals have some Q magic that makes this possible. One of the tricky parts here is to remember for the calculation of the value in t2 that 200 out of the 300 shares at t4 are already taken.

Any suggestion on how to approach this would be much appreciated